# Query multiple table in one tooltips, order form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, join, simpletip

I'm trying to code a tooltip, which uses http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/# simpletip plugin, which returns data via ajax. However, i can't seem to display the data from 3 tables, which is fetched via the data image, as each image is assigned to it's own id. as seen below, i need to display all data from the table, but with 3 tables to read from. in my webpage, a php statement will query data from one table for each category, generated by this tooltips. only a round tooltip came out, not even `mysql_error()`. i need help asap. this is the only site where i seem to get inputs from others.

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK', 1);
require "../connect.php";

if (!$_POST['img'])
    die(mysql_error());

$img = mysql_real_escape_string(end(explode('/', $_POST['img'])));

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic.*,
    non_alcoholic1.* FROM alcoholic INNER JOIN non_alcoholic USING (img) INNER JOIN
    non_alcoholic1 USING (img) WHERE img='" . $img . "' "));

if (!$row)
    die(mysql_error());

echo '<strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong>

    <p class="descr">' . $row['description'] . '</p>

    <strong>price: $' . $row['price'] . '</strong>
    <small>Drag it to your shopping<br /> cart to purchase it</small>';
?>
```

Comment: I've managed to display `non_alcoholic1` content via RIGHT JOIN. However, no data was displayed for both `alcoholic` & `non_alcoholic` table.

Comment: many thanks to @MichaelRushton for his help. I'll revise my code as my eyes cannot stand the sleeplessness.

Comment: I'm happy to announce that I've managed to overcome this problems. Thanks for everyone who look into this. Apparently, i just merge all data into one table named `products`, and query the relevant items using `WHERE`. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing there are three tables with an `img` column? If so, is this what you need?:

```
SELECT
    alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic1.*
FROM
    alcoholic
INNER JOIN non_alcoholic USING (img)
INNER JOIN non_alcoholic1 USING (img)
WHERE
    img = '" . $img . "'
```

**Edit:** When I said update your OP with the new issue I didn't mean overwrite it, I meant add it underneath so that this answer (and others if there were any) make sense.

Anyway, the problem is that `$row['name']`, etc. don't refer to anything in the `SELECT` statement. You need to change `alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic1.*` to what it is you're pulling out, for example:

`SELECT alcoholic.name, alcoholic.description, alcoholic.price ...`

Comment: yes. this is my query statement, which retrieve data via ajax.

        {<?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM non_alcoholic");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     echo '<div class="product"><img src="images/drinks/'.$row['img'].'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'" width="70" height="256" class="pngfix" /></div>';
    }

    ?>}


@MichaelRushton

Comment: dang, i don't know how to post codes properly. and @MichaelRushton, your code didn't work..

Comment: it says this: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\www.bestdrinks.com.my\ajax\tips.php on line 10.

Comment: Then your query failed, meaning you've incorrectly converted my example. What is the exact query you're using?

Comment: here: $row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic1.* FROM alcoholic INNER JOIN non_alcoholic USING  (img) INNER JOIN non_alcoholic1 USING (img) WHERE img='".$img."'"));

thanks for your responses.

Comment: And all three tables have an `img` column? What's the output from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: yes. however, note that the img is independent. here's the output:

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\www.bestdrinks.com.my\ajax\tips.php on line 10
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 681272 {main}( ) ..\tips.php:0
2 0.0049 689688 mysql_fetch_assoc ( ) ..\tips.php:10

Comment: I'm pretty newbie to mysql. would you kindly point me where i should look for mysql_error() ouput?

Comment: Take the `mysql_query()` out of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and assign it to a variable. Then `echo mysql_error()`. Then put the `mysql_query()` variable into the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function.

Comment: it might be better if i provide you the example. let me upload my files. will get back to you. not that I didn't try your solution, but it might help if you get your hands on the whole code.

here:http://www.mediafire.com/?rfdcl4ztj59i5gw

Comment: I've already told you want to do; show us the output from `mysql_error()` after you call `mysql_query()`. This is not the same as the PHP warning you've already given.

Comment: is this it? i replaced die("there is no such product"); with die(mysql_error());

Column 'img' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Are are using `USING (img)` or `ON t1.img = t2.img`?

Comment: I've tried USING (img) and ON t1.img = t2.img . However, should I write ON t1.img='".$img."' = t2.img='".$img."'?

Comment: Use it as I've written above (using proper table names and whatever fields you want selected, obviously).

Comment: now another came up.
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING (img) INNER JOIN non_alcoholic1 USING (img) WHERE img='torre_oria_cava_bru' at line 1

Comment: Can you update your example code in the OP so I can see what you're doing?

Comment: `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic.*, non_alcoholic1.* FROM alcoholic INNER JOIN non_alcoholic ON USING (img) INNER JOIN non_alcoholic1 USING (img) WHERE img='".$img."' "));`

    thanks for your concern. i really appreciate it. i know how people elsewhere ignore newbies, but you didn't.

Comment: You have an `ON` before the `USING`. See my initial answer above. I've written the fixed form of your query.

Comment: oh, I missed that. Well, sorry to trouble you but now nothing came out. Only a round semi-transparent dot of my tooltip is displayed. Not even mysql_error().

Comment: We need to stop having this discussion in the comments. Update your OP with the current script and the current problem(s).